# Displaying Unicode Characters with Arduino

Tags: unicode, utf-8, arduino, keyboard, ascii

I am currently using the [Keyboard.h library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/) on Arduino

I would like to display the following characters upon pressing a button on my breadboard : ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠

I don't know much about ASCII, Unicode and Hexadecimal so I'm having a hard time figuring this out

Does someone know how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are only able to send keys. OS then converts keys to characters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_code_input

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
Pressing Alt+3, Alt+4 etc... is a great way to get around this issue.

However this probably won't work if the computer doesn't have a numpad or is running a different OS

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/91365/70109
for how to convert from unicode to Octal for output

The GCC compiler used by Arduino also does not accept all unicode sequences such as \u0020
Using octal avoids this problem.
[image]

```
Serial.print("\342\204\211");
```

will output ℉ provided the receiver has font for that unicode.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Keyboard.print("\uUNICODE_VALUE");`
Unicode values can be found at: http://www.unicode.org/charts/

If that don't work on linux you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, type the unicode value, and press enter like this:

```
void typeUnicode(int val, int time){
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_CTRL);
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
    Keyboard.press('u');
    delay(time);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(time);
    Keyboard.println(String(val, HEX));
    delay(time);
}
```

On Windows you havel "ALT codes", and i'm not sure how they work since i'm a unix geek.

Comment: Sadly Keyboard.print("\u2665") did not work. It prints the letters "2nw" on the screen. Do you know why ?

Comment: Unicode characters are bigger than a byte, so maybe the arduino's serial monitor don't have support for them, could you try with picocom or putty?